# where should I put client codes in grails?

Tags: grails, groovy

Let's say I have some codes to make 2 rest calls to the other API. And I need a service layer to make 2 rest calls in the same action.

In Java, I probably would do something like this

```
@Service
public class RestService{
   @Autowired
   RestClient restClient

   def shutdown(){
      if(restClient.isSystemGood()){
         restClient.shutdownSystem()
      }          
   }
}

@Repository
public class RestClient {
  boolean isSystemGood() {
    ...
  }

  void shutdownSystem() {
    ...
  }
}
```

How should I fit in grails way to do the similar thing?

- Should I put the logic inside RestClient into a domain class? or Should I put both RestService and RestClient into a domain class? Does domain class have to be backed by a DB?

Because I only see `service` and `domain` folders in the grails default file structure.

Comment: Check out: http://grails.asia/grails-3-project-structure-tutorial

Comment: You can either act like you would in java in a spring application or you can put those two services under the grails-app/services folder to work with the grails convention

Answer (score 0):

RestService (in your simple case a non-transactional one) inside grails-app/services directory is the right place for the logic. Inject the service inside the controller action to use it. 
Injecting services into the domain class is not recommended. It hard to test, degrades the read performance and results in a spaghetti design. This is why Grails now by default, has [disabled the services injection in the domain](http://grailsblog.objectcomputing.com/posts/2017/05/09/injecting-a-service-into-a-domain-class.html) class